# C++ wininter.h '/' in URL string

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, url, web-scraping

I am attempting to load HTML code using C++ and `wininet.h` instrumentation in Visual Studio 2010 Express. To create the URL String, I write the following:

```
HINTERNET hConnect =::InternetConnect(
    hInternet, 
    _T("stackoverflow.com"), 
    INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT, 
    NULL, 
    NULL, 
    IINTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 
    0, 
    1u
);
```

The program works well when the URL is just a domain with no path or protocol, but when I change the URL from `stackoverflow.com` to `http://stackoverflow.com/questions`, suddenly my code doesn't work any longer.

`HttpSendRequest(hRequest, NULL, 0, NULL, 0)` simply returns false.

I have tried a number of different variations on my parameters and have scoured Google, but I am just plain stuck. Can anyone provide some insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa384363%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for `InternetConnect` tells me that it is used to establish an FTP or HTTP connection to a server - not to download a URL.

As such, the `lpszServerName` parameter is [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa384363%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as:

> Pointer to a null-terminated string that specifies the host name of an Internet server. Alternately, the string can contain the IP number of the site, in ASCII dotted-decimal format (for example, 11.0.1.45).

So you must use a server's host name or IP address and cannot use a URL, hence why it doesn't work when you do.

The path part of your URL (`/questions`) should be used as the `lpszObjectName` parameter of a `HttpOpenRequest` call ([docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa384233%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) that you make using the `hConnect` returned by your `InternetConnect` call.